Biot-Savart Law Application Simplification Issues
My goal is to create an expression that gives the field strength of an arced segment of wire at a fixed distance away from the center point of the arc. To be used in EMF (electromotive force) visualization. The following Equation gives this relation:
\begin{equation} d\beta=\frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi}\int_{_{C}}^{}\frac{\overrightarrow{dl}\times \overrightarrow{r'}}{\left| r' \right|^{3}} \end{equation}
Source: Biot-Savart Law
However, I have been having issues getting this into an algebraic expression that can be easily implemented into Code. as when I
represent the cross products of dl and r’ as an expression over the magnitude of r’^3 The simplest I've been able to get it is as follows:
\begin{equation}
d\beta=\frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi}\int_{\alpha_{min}}^{\alpha_{max}}\frac{(cos(\alpha) z)\widehat{i}+(sin(\alpha)z)\widehat{j}+(cos(\alpha)x+sin(\alpha)y+r)\widehat{k}}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+r^{2}+2r(sin(\alpha)y+cos(\alpha)y)^{\frac{3}{2}})}d\alpha
\end{equation}
Steps are shown in the image link below.
Which makes the integration stupidly long. As A and b are equivalent I am trying to use formula a as opposed to b so I don’t end up with a to the power of 3/2 to make integration easier. I’ve been staring at this problem for about 3 weeks now and have tried numerous different thing representing it with respect to beta instead of alpha. As shown in the image below:
The simplest I’ve got it is with respect to alpha as shown on the right-hand side of the page. But the integration is stupidly long. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get that integral in simplest forms? Ideas I’ve had are switching coordinate systems and right now I somehow ended up in a mixture of cylindrical and Cartesian coordinates.

Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

You should learn latex as this site does not encourage the use of links and images. Nevertheless, atleast for now, it's alright as you're a new user.

Alright, I will keep that in mind! I'm relatively new to this asking questions things. Will this make it easier for people to see my question to answer it?

Your goal appears not to be to represent something, but to calculate something; however, it is not very clear what you want to calculate.

@Lieven I would like a generalized case where I can input the distance away from the center point of the arc segment in the XYZ directions and get the result of that integral. The intended application for this is in EMF (Electro Motive Force) visualization and requires an algebraic representation so that it can be represented in code. Does that make sense/is their an edit you would recommend to my post to make my intentions more clear?

@Lieven the integral is taken from biot-savart law as shown below
[ d\beta=\frac{\mu_{0}I}{4\pi}\int_{_{C}}^{}\frac{\overrightarrow{dl}\times \overrightarrow{r'}}{\left| r' \right|^{3}}]
I got the equation from this wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law

It may benefit from more explanation, but at least I can imagine where we are going. The integral (b) reminds me of mechanics, specifically Kepler's second law. The integral is related to the area spanned by the radius vector as the point traverses the curve, although I am not sure what happens if the curve is not planar.

Oh, I see now that the curve is a circle, right?

@Lieven Alright ill rephrase it and provide more background, and yes the curve is a circle

Ok looking around the Internet I get pessimistic about the integral resolving into a closed expression unless the point $p$ is on the axis of the circle.

@Lieven could you clarify resolving? I was able to get the integral to evaluate to an exact value using wolfrum alpha it was just nasty and a ridiculously long-expression. By that I mean if you look at the image in the bottom right hand corner of the page, as x, y, z and r are all constant it can be integrated with respect to alpha. It's just supper gross and disgusting yk?

If Wolfram doesn't simplify it, you should count your blessings imo.

@Lieven I just have this itch that their is a better way to represent this and where it is right now just isn't cutting it lol

by the way, algebraic geometry is something quite different.

$\newcommand{\bvec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
$\newcommand{\uv}[1]{\bvec{\hat{e}}_{#1}}$
Work in the traditional Heaviside–Gibbs vector calculus with cylindrical coordinates $(\rho,\phi,z)$. Let $\bvec{J}$ denote the vector-valued distribution
$$\bvec{J}(\rho,\phi,z)=I \delta(\rho-a)\delta(z)[\phi_1<\phi<\phi_2]\uv{\phi}\text{.}$$
Then the unique suitably regular vector field $\bvec{B}$ satisfying
$$\begin{align}
\bvec{\nabla}\cdot \bvec{B} &= 0 &
\bvec{\nabla}\times \bvec{B} &= \mu_0 \bvec{J}
\end{align}$$
is
$$\bvec{B}(\rho,\phi,z) =\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi\sqrt{(\rho+a)^2+z^2}}\left.\left(
b_{\rho}(\rho,\phi,z;\phi')\uv{\rho}
+b_{\phi}(\rho,\phi,z;\phi')\uv{\phi}
+b_z(\rho,\phi,z;\phi')\uv{z}
\right)\right\rvert_{\phi'=\phi_1}^{\phi_2}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
b_{\rho}(\rho,\phi,z;\phi') &=
\frac{z}{\rho}\left(\frac{a^2+\rho^2+z^2}{(\rho+a)^2+z^2}\Pi\left(\tfrac{\phi'-\phi-\pi}{2},-m(\rho,z)\vert m(\rho,z)\right)-F\left(\tfrac{\phi'-\phi-\pi}{2}\vert m(\rho,z)\right)\right)\\
b_{\phi}(\rho,\phi,z;\phi') &=-\frac{z}{\rho}\sqrt{\frac{(\rho+a)^2+z^2}{a^2+\rho^2+z^2-2a\rho\cos(\phi-\phi')}} \\
b_{z}(\rho,\phi,z;\phi') &=
\frac{a^2-\rho^2-z^2}{(\rho+a)^2+z^2}\Pi\left(\tfrac{\phi'-\phi-\pi}{2},-m(\rho,z)\vert m(\rho,z)\right)+F\left(\tfrac{\phi'-\phi-\pi}{2}\vert m(\rho,z)\right) \\
m(\rho,z) &= \frac{4a\rho}{(\rho+a)^2+z^2}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Here $F(\phi\vert m)$ and $\Pi(\phi,n\vert m)$ are Legendre's incomplete elliptic integrals of the first and third kind in the amplitude-parameter convention
$$\begin{align}
F(\phi\mid m)&=\int_0^{\phi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2 \theta}}\\
\Pi(\phi,n\mid m)&=\int_0^{\phi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{(1-n\sin^2\theta)\sqrt{1-m\sin^2 \theta}}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
This solution in terms of elliptic integrals alone is due to Alberto-Gonzalez and Elam-Cardenas (2021), although the basic idea is a few decades older and the case $\phi_2=\phi_1+2\pi$ is classical. You can find the derivation in their paper: it is a few pages long of computer-assisted algebra.

Alberto Gonzalez, Migdonio, and Dorindo Elam Cardenas. 2021. “Analytical Expressions for the Magnetic Field Generated by a Circular Arc Filament Carrying a Direct Current.” IEEE Access 9:7483–95.
